# Ubuntu 20.10 MATE or Mint (20) 1600x900 resolution starts looking like blocks tabbed to the left

Tags: display-resolution, radeon, 20.10

Hardware: Lenovo L340 with Radeon 3500U
Software: **ubuntu-mate-20.10**-desktop-amd64.iso (also tried Mint same thing as control)

Running L340 with Radeon 3500U (Vega 8 is the windows driver). If I use any other resolution, the screen is fine. Also in Ubuntu and Mint 18 or 19 - resolution was fine, but with upgrade and fresh install, the screen looks like this by default (and setting it in display) for 1600x900.

I can 100% use it well enough to set it a lower resolution and "change" things - just trying to figure out how to get it to show that resolution correct again in 20x.

Refresh is locked at 60hz.

[image: screen at 1600x900]

Comment: You lost me are you running Ubuntu or Mint? If it is Mint this is the wrong place for the question.

Comment: Also there is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.

Comment: Sorry, it's ubuntu-mate-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso.  Tried Mint simply as another version (didn't have Arch or Cent on hand at the time)

Comment: Did you also use Mint MATE edition? It may help to know if the issue is desktop environment dependent.

Comment: Archisman Panigrahi - That was the next thing - and yep. XFCE works just fine. :)   Seems Mate at the moment has some issues. Switching to XFCE now!

Comment: I really can't see how changing a desktop (XFCE) just works; unless you are re-installing?  If it works with XFCE, then I'd compare the differences in the system to those of Ubuntu-MATE, and those will allow you to get Ubuntu-MATE working as you wish (assuming they are the same releases, kernel stack options etc; as Ubuntu LTS releases come with two stack choices and you've provided no details of this; seeming to focus on off-topic Mint).   What is 20x????  20.04 with GA kernel is a different stack to 20.10 or 20.04 using HWE...

Comment: Using the XFCE fresh installed worked. While I normally like to fiddle with the linux stuff, this was not one I wanted to sink hours in so once the fresh install with XFCE worked. I was pretty much good with that. :)